# How to resize table view, when if any data is there and no data in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one screen with the title "current team" , below that one table view will be there, and below that one text field with + button. So when user enter any data in UITextField and if user press + button that data will add in above UITableView

This blow image is my current screen :

[image]
[image]

Now, I my above screen I have designed and added some constraints for that. Now when no data and at least one data in table view, there is more space between the title and the text field.

But what i need is :

I need to show like below image :

[image]

No space I need to show between that title and text field. And when at least one data is there in table view, the height of the table view should increase and the text field also should need to come below .

How can i handle this :

I did like this  :

```
if currentTeams.visibleCells.count == 0 {

        tableViewHeight.constant = 5
    }

    else{
        tableViewHeight.constant = 50

    }
```

**Current team = table view name**

But it din work, Please help me out. How can I do that?

Code snip :

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.isEqual(currentTeams) {
            return teamNames.count
        }
        return pastTeamNames.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView.isEqual(currentTeams) {
            return getCellForRow(indexPath)
        }
        return getCellForPastTeamsRow(indexPath)
    }
```

Comment: did you tried,
self.view.setNeedsLayout()

Comment: I am new to handle ios, by seeing some tutorial i set some height constraint and i tried that. But i din try any other

Comment: if currentTeams.visibleCells.count == 0 {

        tableViewHeight.constant = 5
      self.view.setNeedsLayout() 
    }

    else{
        tableViewHeight.constant = 50
        self.view.setNeedsLayout() 
    }

Comment: You could add a `footerView` to your tableView and add `textFieldView` to your  `footerView`? .this way you dont need to change `row height` or anything.code tested in `Swift3` and its works.

Comment: @Joe  due u have any tuttorial for this footerview ??

Comment: i did everything programatically. `myTableView?.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:40))` and set your `textField` same size as `footerView` an add subView to your `footerView`...this way when the view loads you only see the `footerView` and you can append tableView data by add or remove to populate the `tableView`.code bit tricky but works.hope this helps

Comment: But if i add any data, does the table view increase and the text field will come down respectively ??

Comment: Yes.tableview populate dynamically according to textfield input.try workout yourself and let me know.i have few simple bugs when I run the code it fixable.but I don't want to spend my time on it to fix.thats why I didn't upload my answer.hope you understand.cheers

Comment: @mack check my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your table hight constrain.
@IBOutlet var current_team_tablehight: NSLayoutConstraint! 
 @IBOutlet var playpast_role_table_hight: NSLayoutConstraint!
 @IBOutlet var past_team_table_hight: NSLayoutConstraint!
 @IBOutlet var certificate_table_hight: NSLayoutConstraint!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // put it as 0 for default 
        current_team_tablehight.constant = 0
        certificate_table_hight.constant = 0
        past_team_table_hight.constant = 0
        playpast_role_table_hight.constant = 0 
 }



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        if profileData.FirstName.length > 0 {
            // data available for that table then . 
            currentTeams.reloadData()
            current_team_tablehight.constant = currentTeams.contentSize.height + 5;
            pastTeams.reloadData()
            past_team_table_hight.constant = pastTeams.contentSize.height + 5;

            playedTableView.reloadData()
            playpast_role_table_hight.constant = playedTableView.contentSize.height + 5;

            certificationtableview.reloadData()
            certificate_table_hight.constant = certificationtableview.contentSize.height + 5;
   }
}


func deleteTeamFromCurrentTeams(sender: UIButton) {
        let but = sender
        let view = but.superview!
        let cell = view.superview as! CurrentTeamsTableViewCell
        if let tblView = cell.superview?.superview as? UITableView {

            if tblView.isEqual(self.currentTeams) {
                let indexPath = currentTeams.indexPathForCell(cell)
                teamNames.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)

                currentTeams.reloadData()
                if teamNames.count > 0 {
                    current_team_tablehight.constant = currentTeams.contentSize.height;
                }else{
                    current_team_tablehight.constant = 0;
                }

            }
            else if tblView.isEqual(self.pastTeams) {
                let indexPath = pastTeams.indexPathForCell(cell)
                pastTeamNames.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)

                pastTeams.reloadData()
                if pastTeamNames.count > 0 {
                    past_team_table_hight.constant = pastTeams.contentSize.height;
                }else{
                    past_team_table_hight.constant = 0;
                }

            }
            else if tblView.isEqual(self.playedTableView) {

                let indexPath = playedTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
                playedTeamNames.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)

                playedTableView.reloadData()
                if playedTeamNames.count > 0 {
                    playpast_role_table_hight.constant = playedTableView.contentSize.height;
                }else{
                    playpast_role_table_hight.constant = 0;
                }

            }

            else
            {
                let indexPath = certificationtableview.indexPathForCell(cell)
                ExpTeamNames.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)

                certificationtableview.reloadData()
                if ExpTeamNames.count > 0 {
                    certificate_table_hight.constant = certificationtableview.contentSize.height;
                }else{
                    certificate_table_hight.constant = 0;
                }


            }


        }
        self.view .layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view .setNeedsLayout()

    }
 @IBAction func addPastTeamsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if pastTeamName.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "" && pastTeamName.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "-" {
            pastTeamNames.append(pastTeamName.textVal)
            pastTeamName.text = ""
            pastTeams.reloadData()
             past_team_table_hight.constant = pastTeams.contentSize.height + 5;

        }
    }


    @IBAction func addTeamsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if teamName.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "" && teamName.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "-" {
            teamNames.append(teamName.textVal)
            teamName.text = ""
            currentTeams.reloadData()
            current_team_tablehight.constant = currentTeams.contentSize.height + 5;
        }


    }

    // for played role
    @IBAction func addPlayedTeamsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if playedTeam.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "" && playedTeam.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "-" {
            playedTeamNames.append(playedTeam.textVal)
            playedTeam.text = ""
            playedTableView.reloadData()
            playpast_role_table_hight.constant = playedTableView.contentSize.height + 5;
        }



    }


    @IBAction func addcertificatecoursePressed(sender: AnyObject) {


        if Experience.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "" && Experience.text?.trimWhiteSpace != "-" {
            ExpTeamNames.append(Experience.textVal)
            Experience.text = ""
            certificationtableview.reloadData()
            certificate_table_hight.constant = certificationtableview.contentSize.height + 5;
        }


    }
```

Output :

[image: default screen]

[image: Multiple data]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same by taking a **fix UITableviewCell** at the and of your table. If You have no data initially then in `numberOfRowsInSection` method `return 1`.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (<Your Array>.count > 1) ? <Your Array>.count + 1 : 1;
}
```

This 1 is for that static cell which contains your `UITextField` and `UIButton` for **Plus**.
So `cellForRow` method will be as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      if (<Your Array>.count > 1)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < <Your Array>.count - 1)
        {
//        Initialize your UITableview cell which you have design to show your list
//            Your Code to show the list.
//            return your cell
        }
        if (indexPath.row==<Your Array>.count-1 ) {
//            Initialize and return the cell which you have design using UITextField and "Plus" Button
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //            Initialize and return the cell which you have design using UITextField and "Plus" Button
    }
```

Your design will be like

[image]

You can also check example [From Github Here](https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/DynamicTableViewIOS).

Comment: How can i take the fix uitable view cell, can you please give me some code snip. I am new to handle ios. So if i saw some code then it will be helpfull for me

Comment: For your reference i have attached my table view delegate methods

Comment: @ Er. Vihar Shah    sure,

Comment: bro i tried but i was not able to implemnt that. I am dtruk for past 3 hours, If it possibel shall i send my projec to u. Can u help me for one screen,so that i can understnd the flow and i will implement for all my screens

Comment: E-mail ID: vihar.rahatech@gmail.com.Mail me your code here. I'll get on this after my office hours and then I'll mail you working copy back.

Comment: please check ur mail bro

Answer (score 0):

you can have dynamic cell height by setting tableView row height to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. and also you need to provide estimated height. so in your viewdidload add this code:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 // or your estimated height
```

then use autolayout in your tableview cell to adjust items and container height

Comment: So Bythis code it will help for that table view cell to adjust the item `if currentTeams.visibleCells.count == 0 {

        tableViewHeight.constant = 5
    }

    else{
        tableViewHeight.constant = 50

    }`

Comment: @mack by this code you tell tableview that you want autolayout to set heights for cells. then you use autolayout to set heights. you can find a good tutorial here [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Answer (score 0):

Setup your constraints like so-

- First you should have a `UILabel` for "Current Teams" with a leading, trailing and top constraint to the superView.
- Add the `UITableView` below it with a leading, trailing and top to the `UILabel` and a fixed height with a priority of 250, lets put it at 0 initially.
- Add the `UITextField` with a leading, trailing, fixed height, top to the `UITableView` and bottom spacing to the superView with a `>=0`

This will allow the `UITextField` always stick to the bottom of your `UITableView`.

Make an outlet for the `UITableView` height constraint in your `UIViewController`. 
Now if you can use a default `UITableViewCell` height, then your job is easier otherwise you will have to calculate the amount of height each string will take inside the cell and get that value. In your `viewDidLoad` update the `UITableView` height constraint to be -

```
//do this after you do the insertion into the tableview

tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = numberOfRows * rowHeight

view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You will have to update this height every time you add or delete a row in the `UITableView`. As soon as your cells take up the entire screen, the height constraint will break and the `UITextField` will be stuck at the bottom and your `UITableView` will become scrollable.

**Edit:** You have to re-add the height constraint programmatically once it breaks **and** the `UITableView` stops taking up the entire screen.

Comment: That `tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = numberOfRows * rowHeight
` throw some error for number of Rows * row Height . What is that ??

Comment: They are basically variables. `numberOfRows` will be the count of the rows that are to be displayed and `rowHeight` is the height of each row! If you don't assign them the proper values and set the constraints how i explained, this will not work!

Comment: my default row height = 50, and in varibale of `numberOfRows` and `rowHeight` i can set any value  ??