# How to add options list in iOS app using swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS programming. I am working on an app that will ask user to choose his/her blood group from a **drop down options menu**. I want to build it **programmatically**. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Maybe you should use `UIPickerView`

Comment: i've used it, but view shows up in bottom of the app. i want that dropdown inside of a textfield.

Comment: Then you have to use TableView, with custom drop-down like animation.

Comment: can u plz elaborate, like a link to somewhere or some piece of code.

Comment: you  can found more control in https://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41074592/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41084776/6656894 refer this question and use that 3rd party library for dropdown

Answer (score 1):

you can use this lib,Its very good and dev friendly and easily customised

- [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown)

Its very simple to implement just in some lines of code ,Sample to use in Swift,Also check the sample in github

```
    dropDown = DropDown()

    // The view to which the drop down will appear on
    dropDown.anchorView = inputToolbar // your textfield
    dropDown.direction = .Top
    dropDown.dataSource = [String] //your datasource
```